# Signature validation always returns False

Tags: python, cryptography, webhooks, hmac

I am trying to validate the post request coming from Typeform. Their docs on how to do it are [here](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/secure-your-webhooks/#validate-payload-from-typeform), BUT it does not work. So I have implemented the following :

```
def verifySignature(request):
    WEBHOOK_SECRET = os.environ.get('TYPEFORM_SECRET_KEY')
    received_sign = request.headers.get('typeform-signature').split('sha256=')[-1].strip()
    secret = WEBHOOK_SECRET.encode()
    expected_sign = HMAC(key=secret, msg=request.data, digestmod=sha256).hexdigest()
    if str(expected_sign) != str(received_sign):
        return False
    return True
```

The problem is that the function never returns True, it always returns False (and yes, I have ensured the env variable is correct). Thank you!

Comment: What do you think is a bug in the code from the docs that you are implementing new code? And couldn't the problem also be in the data?

Comment: @Topaco I have found it ! In their docs, they don't extract the signature from the header. If you do end up refactoring for that , it works !  But I still don't know what's the problem with the above ... Thank you !